# Searching for and altering an Object in an arraylist

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList that contains Objects. What I have been wanting/needing to do is search for a specific Object within the ArrayList and alter one of it's values if found. I.E. I have a team of Football Players, say Philadelphia Eagles that contains the team name, total points scored total sacks, and then lists all the players by first name, last name, games played, and position. I am looking for a specific player say Chad Hall and I want to remove him from the Eagles and trade him to the New England Patriots. What I have so far is the iteration of the ArrayList but my code isn't finding the player and then exits out.

```
case 6:
           String name = "";
           System.out.print("Who would you like to trade? ");
           name = kb.nextLine();
           tradePlayer(nflTeams, name);

public static void tradePlayer(ArrayList<Team> nflTeams, String name)
  {
     Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
     String teamName = "";
     System.out.print("What team do you want to trade this player to?(Team Acronym) "    );
     teamName = kb.nextLine();

     for(Team t: nflTeams){
        if (nflTeams.contains(name.toLowerCase()))
                      t.setName(teamName);
                }
     System.out.println("Cannot find " + name);
  }
```

The `Player` class involved constructed players by firstname, lastname, team, position, played. What I want to alter is the team. In the `Team` class I have the `setName(String)` to set team names.

Any suggestions or thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: Mmn the contains looks dodgy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (nflTeams.contains(name.toLowerCase()))`

What are you trying to do? Your list `nflTeams` contains `Team` objects not names.
This can not work.
If you need to access a `Team` via its `name` then use `Map<String,Team>` instead

Answer (score 0):

You must get list of players from team and delete from there by specified `name` like:

```
String teamToAddNewPlayer = "New England Patriots";
String deletedPlayer = null;
for(Team t: nflTeams){
      List<String> players = t.getPlayers();
      if (players.contains(name)){
          deletedPlayer = players.remove(name);
      }
      if (t.getName().equals(teamToAddNewPlayer))
          players.add(name);
}
if (deletedPlayer == null)
//nothing was deleted
else
//player was deleted
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of Iterator will give you more control to what you are trying.

```
import java.util.*;

 class IteratorDemo {


public static void main(String args[]) {
      // Create an array list
      ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
      // add elements to the array list
      al.add("C");
      al.add("A");
      al.add("E");
      al.add("B");
      al.add("D");
      al.add("F");

  // Use iterator to display contents of al
  System.out.print("Original contents of al: ");
  Iterator itr = al.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext()) {
     Object element = itr.next();
     System.out.print(element + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();

  // Modify objects being iterated
  ListIterator litr = al.listIterator();
  while(litr.hasNext()) {
     Object element = litr.next();
     litr.set(element + "+");
  }
  System.out.print("Modified contents of al: ");
  itr = al.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext()) {
     Object element = itr.next();
     System.out.print(element + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();

  // Now, display the list backwards
  System.out.print("Modified list backwards: ");
  while(litr.hasPrevious()) {
     Object element = litr.previous();
     System.out.print(element + " ");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
}
```

this example is from [source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm)